# Метод: получить из файла всё после строки номер 2

Tags: c#

Какой метод для чтения файлов существует для того, чтобы получить из файла всё что записано после строки, к примеру, номер `2`?

Comment: Ваши попытки???

Comment: Во время построчного чтения пропускаем первые 2 строки, как-то так.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
var content = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы гениальны!